# what is exactly object file and how to open it

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

```
g++ myCppFile -o myOut
```

I do not know about compiling procedure. But all I want to know is what is the type of `myOut`? It is not text. It is not like configuration file. So what is it ?

And how to see its content?

Comment: Read `man file`, `man objdump`. Or, read `man g++` which says, in part `
       -o file  
           Place output in file file.  This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object
           file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.`

Comment: Arguably this isn't the best site for this type of question - try programmers.stackexchange.com or (for more specific questions) stackoverflow.com

Comment: Understand linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do/33690144#33690144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object file is an intermediate file produced by a compiler during the steps it takes to produce an executable file.

First the compiler reduces the source code to an object file, in which the machine code for the final product has been mostly produced, and variables and other human readable items have been replaced by tokens.

Secondly, the linker takes the object file and the libraries requested by the compiler, and puts together the final executable, rendering the tokens in the object file to addresses that a machine can interpret.

Comment: But myOut is not object file. It would be if gcc was run with -c flag.

Answer (score 0):

`myOut` is a binary file. It consists of zeros and ones in a format readable by processor and kernel. If you need, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030238/linux-executable-binary-file-format) you can find more information.

Comment: I am not sure about binary but +1 for link

Comment: That's a little bit like saying a kitten is a quantity of matter comprised of protons, neutrons and electrons.  Correct but not helpful ;)